# I have to restart transmission-daemon to make transmission-remote work

Tags: raspbian, headless

I have a small problem with my headless raspbian torrentbox, when I reboot transmission-daemon is running:

```
simone@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo service transmission-daemon status
[sudo] password for simone: 
● transmission-daemon.service - Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-05-01 10:49:47 EDT; 3min 13s ago
 Main PID: 526 (transmission-da)
   Status: "Uploading 2318.44 KBps, Downloading 39.32 KBps."
   CGroup: /system.slice/transmission-daemon.service
           └─526 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error

May 01 10:49:45 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Transmission BitTorrent Daemon...
May 01 10:49:47 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Transmission BitTorrent Daemon.
May 01 10:49:49 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[526]: [2017-05-01 10:49:49.514 EDT] UDP Failed to set receive buffer: requested 4194304, got 327680 (tr-udp.c:78)
May 01 10:49:49 raspberrypi transmission-daemon[526]: [2017-05-01 10:49:49.515 EDT] UDP Failed to set send buffer: requested 1048576, got 327680 (tr-udp.c:89)
```

but transmission-remote is not working:

```
[2017-05-01 10:54:15.719 EDT] transmission-remote:  (http://localhost:9091/transmission/rpc/) Couldn't connect to server
```

When I restart transmission-daemon transmission-remote starts working again, do you have any idea why?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Try to enable "Wait for Network at Boot" at `sudo raspi-config`, this works for me